# WPF CompositeCollection grouping by each collection view

Tags: c#, wpf, compositecollection

I've set up a `CompositeCollection` containing two or more collections as follows (simplified):

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionA" Source="{Binding CollectionA}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionB" Source="{Binding CollectionB}" />
    <CompositeCollection x:Key="FullCollection">
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionA}}" />
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionB}}" />
    </CompositeCollection>
</Grid.Resources>
```

...

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource FullCollection}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
```

And then some columns displayed inside the `GridView`. However, I can't seem to be able to add `GroupDescriptions` to the `CompositeCollection`, only the individual `CollectionViewSource` elements.

What I want to do is group by the collections themselves, such that the `ListView` has a header, then the first collection's contents, another header, then the second collection's contents, etc.

Am I barking up the wrong tree trying to group these in this way?

Comment: Nobody? Dan did you find any workaround?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but for a drop down combobox. The solution was to simply had some disabled items inbetween the collections, e.g. adapting to your problem it would be something like:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionA" Source="{Binding CollectionA}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionB" Source="{Binding CollectionB}" />
    <CompositeCollection x:Key="FullCollection">
        <ListViewItem IsEnabled="False">Collection A:</ListViewItem>
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionA}}" />
        <ListViewItem IsEnabled="False">Collection B:</ListViewItem>
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionB}}" />
    </CompositeCollection>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: You can't grouping dynamic collections.

Comment: @JokeHuang it worked for me, what do you mean?

Comment: Your group name is static, can not change at the run time, and can not group by different properties at the run time.